# Import H.264 videos into Final Cut Pro X

Tags: video, import, final-cut-pro, h.264

I tried to import an H.264 video into Final Cut Pro X without success. The software tells me that the file is not importable.

[VideoSpec](http://videospec.free.fr/) shows me the following video track parameters:

- Format:  H.264/MPEG-4 AVC
- Bitrate:  Max.: Undefined / Average: 725 Kbps / Min.: Undefined
- Frame rate (fps):  Max.: Undefined / Average: 25.000 / Min.: Undefined
- Encoding profile:  High@L3.0
- Image size:  720*576
- Pixel Aspect Ratio:  Undefined
- Display Aspect Ratio:  16:9
- Interlacing:  Progressive

Answer (score 1):

Try using Clipwrap. It can quickly convert a lot of error-prone footage for you. there is a free demo available that outputs watermarks.